# Find object by value in array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of objects in PHP, like so:

```
[Places] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [PlaceId] => 837
                [Name] => United Arab Emirates
                [Type] => Country
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [PlaceId] => 838
                [Name] => Afghanistan
                [Type] => Country
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [PlaceId] => 839
                [Name] => Antigua and Barbuda
                [Type] => Country
            )
    )
```

How can I retrieve the Object inside this array if I only know the value of PlaceId, such as 837?

Answer (score 2):

A simple `foreach` loop will do the job:

```
foreach ($places as $place) {
    if ($place->PlaceId == 837) break;
}
if ($place->PlaceId == 837) 
    print_r($place);
else
    echo "Not found!";
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
    (
         [PlaceId] => 837
         [Name] => United Arab Emirates
         [Type] => Country
    )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0a8VU)

It may be faster to use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on the `PlaceId` values, which you can access using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
if (($k = array_search(837, array_column($places, 'PlaceId'))) !== false) {
    print_r($places[$k]);
}
else {
    echo "Not found!";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qH2eC)

Comment: Is there any better solution time complexity Big-O wise?  I would need to place this in another loop, which will be a time complexity of O(n^2)

Comment: @GregoryR. using `array_search` may be faster. Other than that, you could build a hash of the `PlaceId` values and search using that...

Answer (score 0):

With `array_search` and `array_column()`,

```
$key = array_search(839, array_column($places['Places'], 'PlaceId'));
print_r($places['Places'][$key]);
```

**Output:**

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [PlaceId] => 839 
  [Name] => Canada 
  [Type] => Country
 )
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/RsPr4